# XPath to find last text node in element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

How can I select the last text in element `a`?

The element can have children elements.

```
<a>bla di bla <b>foo bar</b> yes!</a>
```

should give me "yes!" and

```
<a>bla di bla <b>foo bar</b></a>
```

should give me "foo bar" and

```
<a>bla di bla</a>
```

should give me "bla die bla"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `//a/descendant::text()[last()]`, that selects the three text nodes

```
 yes!
foo bar
bla di bla
```

in the sample

```
<body>
<a>bla di bla <b>foo bar</b> yes!</a>
<a>bla di bla <b>foo bar</b></a>
<a>bla di bla</a>
</body>
```

online sample with XQuery at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kn.

The suggested path expression `//a/descendant::text()[last()]` works with XPath 1 and later.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
(/a//text())[last()]
```

will select the last text node among the text nodes descendents of `a`.

---

**Update:** OP has indicated that there could be multiple `a` elements in the document and would like the last text node descendent to be select for every `a` element.

This XPath 2.0 expression,

```
for $a in //a 
  return ($a//text())[last()]
```

will satisfy the updated requirements.

Comment: this gives me the last text in the last a. i need the last text from all the a elements

Comment: @Vruchtvet: Answer updated to address your clarified requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Use this Xpath:

```
//*/text()[last()]
```

Comment: That would return multiple text nodes for a single `a` element -- clearly not what OP requested.